# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSEntityDescription 0x7fc863f27230> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i try to learn core data it is fully basic . unfortunately  this error throwing

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key title.

so by this time app terminate.

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

what should i do ? what am i missing thanks

Here is the code in viewcontroller

```
 @IBAction func createMangeObjectBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context  =  appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let entityForName =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        entityForName?.setValue("iOS Programming", forKey: "title")
        entityForName?.setValue("12/12/12", forKey: "publishDate")
        entityForName?.setValue("NH001", forKey: "code")
        entityForName?.setValue("tolight", forKey: "author")


        do{
           try context.save()
            print("saved")
        }
        catch{
          print("something happend")
        }

    }
```

Here is the model:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
let entityForName =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: context)
```

creates a `NSEntityDescription` and not an object of that entity.

What you want is

```
let book = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: context)
book.setValue("iOS Programming", forKey: "title")
// ...
```

Or better, create a `NSManagedObject` subclass for the entity
and use the property accessors directly:

```
let book = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Book", inManagedObjectContext: context)
book.title = "iOS Programming"
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `NSEntityDescription` here NOT a `NSManagedObject`. A entity description describes a database entries fields and types . Its not a database entry in itself.

`class func entity(forEntityName entityName: String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSEntityDescription?`

To create the instance of `Book` i.e 1 record in your database you need to take that description and pass it to the init method

`init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto: NSManagedObjectContext?)`

so

`let newBook = NSManagedObject(entityForName,insertInto:context)`